# How to create a Sub-Groups under a Group

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to see if we can create below structure in GitLab

```
Group
   Business A
      ProjectA
      ProjectB
   Business B
      ProjectA
      ProjectB
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in the current release of GitLab. If you really want this feature you can request a feature [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues).

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with GitLab 9.0 CE/EE, which is due to be released on 22nd March 2017

You can download the latest packages as shown in https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/

Once downloaded and installed, You can then have the ability to create hierarchical groups. All the documentation is available in the link below

https://gitlab.com//help/user/group/subgroups/index.md